# Why do permenantly deleted files in Windows take up data and not disappear?

Tags: windows, 7-zip, recycle-bin

So with **permenantly deleted** files, I expect them to be marked off as raw data and disappear forever, to be overwritten eventually. But then, why do they not disappear in 7zip?! They even supposably take up 544 bytes (Not sure, it didn't specify unit).
To replicate it:

1. Download 7zip if you haven't yet.
2. Get some files to delete.
3. Send them to Recycle Bin.
4. Empty it or delete them.
5. Open 7zip and go the C: drive and enter $Recycle.Bin, then find the correct folder for your recycle bin. (The correct one will let you access it).
6. You will see some files with a `$` prefix with alphanumeric names for them, file extensions may be preserved.

Comment: It looks like 7-zip uses similar function calls as recovery tools to see the remnants of the deleted files. The "$" prefix is related to the way Windows marks the space as "available for overwriting", but if it hasn't already been overwritten, 7-zip can see it. I can't find any confirmation that this is an intentional feature of 7-zip -- searching for any phrase near "recover deleted files" yields lots of general data recovery tools.

Comment: And looking further, 7-zip only shows those that are still in the Recycle Bin. Once I empty the bin completely, 7-zip shows nothing. I'll keep trying to reproduce.

Comment: I am certain that it does occur. Once, I deleted a directory and it showed up as ```something```.minecraft (Just as an example). Seems like the Recycle Bin isn't perfect.

Comment: A recyclebin is a normal folder with special shell parameters. as a result, it is possible to get a corrupted recycle bin. In that case, deleted files should reappear in the recyclebin. Also, the recyclebin has files for all users, but only files deleted by your user will show. You may therefor be looking at files deleted by another user.

Comment: No, I am not looking at the wrong folder. I have used a regular user account to prove this. And they definetly do not reappear in the Recycle Bin.